# Por que as divs estão dobrando?

Tags: html, css, div

Tenho um código de uma página que está acontecendo algo que desconheço: tenho duas divs containers com largura 100%, e cada uma tem outras divs dentro.

No entanto, após adcionar um novo container com largura 100%, e colocar novas divs dentro, ocorre que, dentro dos primeiros containers, a última div, que fica por último, dobra, ou seja, vai para baixo numa nova linha.

Porém os cálculos estão certos, só dobra após adicionar uma nova div dentro do container novo. Vou mandar o código aqui abaixo, e alguém por gentileza pode me ajudar?

```css
body{background-color: #DDDDDD}
#geral{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box{
  float: left;
}

#container1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#container2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#container3{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

/*PRIMEIRA LINHA*/
#segundalinha{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 215px; height: 80px;
  background-color: #4e5154;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/*FIM PRIMEIRA LINHA*/
/*SEGUNDA LINHA*/
#ativos{
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 180px; height: 170px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#status{
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 244px; height: 170px;
  background-color: #1461c4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#instalados{
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 223px; height: 170px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#recebimentos{
  margin-left: 8px;
  width: 660px; height: 170px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*FIM SEGUNDA LINHA*/
/*TERCEIRA LINHA*/
#graficos{
  width: 438px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/*FIM TERCEIRA LINHA*/
```

```html
<div id="geral">
  <!- PRIMEIRA LINHA ->
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">NOVOS PEDIDOS</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Aprovados</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Reprovados</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">REATIVAÇOES</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Instalações</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Manutenções</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">INSTALAÇÕES</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Instaladas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Canceladas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">ATEND. EXTERNO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Abertas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Finalizadas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">MANUTENÇÕES</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Abertas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Finalizadas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
    <div id="segundalinha" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/pedidos.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;">
<h6 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:6px; left:75px; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">NOVOS PEDIDOS INTERNET</h6>-->
      <div style=" position:absolute; width: 205px; height: 78px; top:1px; left:5px;">
        <table style="position absolute; font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:205px; height:78px; text-align:left; line-height:10px; color:#FFF">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; font-size:12px;">RETIRADAS</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Dia</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Mês</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; width:42px;">Ano</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Abertas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px;">Finalizadas</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; font-weight:bold;">Pendentes</td>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">90000</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; top:43px; left:5px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; color:#FFF">Pendentes: 55</h5>-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!- FIM PRIMEIRA LINHA ->
  <!- SEGUNDA LINHA ->
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="ativos" class="box">
      <!--<img src="icones/ativos.png" style="width:55px; height:55px; position:absolute; top:15px; left:11px;">-->
      <H5 style="margin:12 0 0 53; font-family:arial; line-height:100%; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; ">CLIENTES ATIVOS</H5>
      <!--<h2 style="position:absolute; margin: 0px; top: 40px; left: 74px; color: #FFF;">10.376</h2>

<hr width="158px" style="position:absolute; top:85px; left:11px; border:1px solid #428bca">-->
      <div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top:14px; width:160px; height:105px";>
        <table border="1px" style="width:160px; height:120px; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">
          <tr>
            <td>PAGANTES</td> <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>INTERNOS</td> <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>GRATUITOS</td> <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>PARCEIROS</td> <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>TOTAL</td> <td style="text-align:right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="status" class="box">
      <H5 style="margin: 8 0 0 80;font-family:arial; font-weight:normal; color:#FFF">STATUS DOS CLIENTES</H5>
      <div style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 14px; width:222px; height:138px;">
        <table border="1" style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:222px; height:114px; color:#FFF; border-color:#FFF;">
          <tr>
            <td>Tipo</td> <td style="text-align: right;">Qtd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2 - Pendência Financeira</td> <td style="text-align: right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4 - Aviso de Bloqueio</td> <td style="text-align: right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5 - Bloqueado 1ª Mensalidade</td> <td style="text-align: right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6 - Bloq. Aut. Falta Pagamento</td> <td style="text-align: right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>9 - Bloq. Man. Falta Pagamento</td> <td style="text-align: right;">90000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="instalados" class="box">
      <img src="icones/ion.png" style="width:45px; height:45px; margin:10 0 0 10; position: absolute;">
      <!--<h5 style="position:absolute; margin:0px; top:15px; left:74px; font-family:arial; line-height:100%;">CLIENTES INSTALADOS</h5>-->
      <div style=" width:138px; height:165px; margin:auto; margin-left:60px; margin-top:5px;">
        <table style="font-size:12px; font-family:arial; width:145px; height:140px;">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">CLIENTES INSTALADOS</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DIA</td> <td>MÊS</td> <td>ANO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>90000</td> <td>90000</td> <td>90000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">STBS INSTALADOS</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DIA</td> <td>MÊS</td> <td>ANO</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>90000</td> <td>90000</td> <td>90000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recebimentos" class="box">
      <img src="icones/local.png" style="width:55px; height:55px">
      <h5>RECEBIMENTOS LOCAL MÊS</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!- FIM SEGUNDA LINHA ->

  <!- TERCEIRA LINHA ->
  <div id="container3">
    <div id="graficos" class="box"></div>
    <div id="graficos" class="box"></div>
    <div id="graficos" class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <!- FIM TERCEIRA LINHA->

</div>
```

Comment: descobri o proeblema, o body estava com tamanho menor que a largura dos container e das divs, bastei adcionar um tamanho fixo maior que eles que ficou tudo certo!

Comment: O problema era que a largura da página estava menor que a largura das divs, então obviamente, a última como não tem espaço vai para baixo. Bastei aumentar o tamanho da dív geral que resolveu!